# Удалить содержимое кнопки при нажатии одной из них

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="site-index" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Report">
            Report
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Orders">
            Orders
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Event">
            Event
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Shop_Info">
            Shop_Info
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Products">
            Products
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Customer">
            Customer
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Theme">
            Theme
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Location">
            Location
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Collection">
            Collection
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">

        <div id="Report" class="collapse">
          fasfageda
        </div>
        <div id="Orders" class="collapse">
          ewg
        </div>
        <div id="Event" class="collapse">
          segw
        </div>
        <div id="Shop_Info" class="collapse">
          egre
        </div>
        <div id="Products" class="collapse">
          rdhbdb
        </div>
        <div id="Customer" class="collapse">
          gsehrfg
        </div>
        <div id="Theme" class="collapse">
          5543ge4r
        </div>
        <div id="Location" class="collapse">
          4ty343
        </div>
        <div id="Collection" class="collapse">
          876jurfsd
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

У меня есть такая html, помогите сделать так, чтобы при нажатии одного button-а остольные исчезли. В представленном коде все работают вместе, как сделать это на html?

Comment: На html - никак. На js - не очень трудно

Comment: а можеш  показать пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('button').not(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-index" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Report">
            Report
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Orders">
            Orders
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Event">
            Event
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Shop_Info">
            Shop_Info
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Products">
            Products
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Customer">
            Customer
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Theme">
            Theme
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Location">
            Location
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Collection">
            Collection
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">

        <div id="Report" class="collapse">
          fasfageda
        </div>
        <div id="Orders" class="collapse">
          ewg
        </div>
        <div id="Event" class="collapse">
          segw
        </div>
        <div id="Shop_Info" class="collapse">
          egre
        </div>
        <div id="Products" class="collapse">
          rdhbdb
        </div>
        <div id="Customer" class="collapse">
          gsehrfg
        </div>
        <div id="Theme" class="collapse">
          5543ge4r
        </div>
        <div id="Location" class="collapse">
          4ty343
        </div>
        <div id="Collection" class="collapse">
          876jurfsd
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

UPD:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><button data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</button></li>
  <li><button data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</button></li>
  <li><button data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</button></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: кажется вы не поняли вопрос говорю исчезли не buttoni а содержимое button щв в каждем buttonу есть содержимое вот они <div id="Report" class="collapse"> fasfageda </div> <div id="Orders" class="collapse"> ewg </div> и т. д.

Comment: @Aram77778 вопрос я понял правильно, вы не правильно задаете)

Comment: ))) нет просто мой вопрос изменили и он стал таким

Comment: @Aram77778 тогда используйте табы) если я вас правильно понял, то при нажатии на кнопку нужно переключать содержимое?

Comment: переключение работает по id  он вытаскывает содержимое data-target="#Products" но он работает все вместе я хочу чтоб при клике одного button остольные содержимые исчезли осталось содержимое только етого id

Comment: сорри не увидел что ты изменил  ответ сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

Теперь убирает контент. Но всеж лучше это на jQuery сделать. Ломанулся я делать на нативном так как на jQuery уже было.

```js
function onClick(event) {
          let _this = event.target;
          let {parentNode} = _this;
          let {toggle, target} = _this.dataset;
          //вернем все
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.${toggle}`))
            .forEach(item => item.style.display = "");
          //убираем все кроме необходимиого
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.${toggle}:not(${target})`))
            .forEach(item => item.style.display="none");
    }
```

```html
<div class="site-index" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Report" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Report
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Orders" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Orders
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Event" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Event
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Shop_Info" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Shop_Info
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Products" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Products
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Customer" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Customer
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Theme" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Theme
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Location" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Location
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Collection" onClick="onClick(event)">
            Collection
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">

        <div id="Report" class="collapse">
          fasfageda
        </div>
        <div id="Orders" class="collapse">
          ewg
        </div>
        <div id="Event" class="collapse">
          segw
        </div>
        <div id="Shop_Info" class="collapse">
          egre
        </div>
        <div id="Products" class="collapse">
          rdhbdb
        </div>
        <div id="Customer" class="collapse">
          gsehrfg
        </div>
        <div id="Theme" class="collapse">
          5543ge4r
        </div>
        <div id="Location" class="collapse">
          4ty343
        </div>
        <div id="Collection" class="collapse">
          876jurfsd
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: можете сказать что делает у вас __let {
    target
  } = event;__  данная строка ???

Comment: это равносильно `let target = event.target;`

Comment: кажется  вы не поняли вопрос говорю исчезли не buttoni а содержимое button щв в каждем buttonу есть  содержимое вот они  <div id="Report" class="collapse">
          fasfageda
        </div>
        <div id="Orders" class="collapse">
          ewg
        </div> и т. д.

Comment: @Aram77778 поменял